# How add a new element or modify one in a MatOfPoint3f ? (OpenCV, Java)

Tags: java, opencv

I am usig the OpenCV api for java. And I'm trying to use the MatOfPoint3f element.
I find that you can initialize and insert all the data you need but once.
After I insert some data, I want to add new data or modify an element.

How can I do that?

I have to try it, but when I insert new data using the methods .fromArray() or .fromList() of the class MatOfPoint3f, the data, already inserted, is cleared, and just the new data stays there.

I have this code

```
    int i = 2;
    int j = 4;
    double k = 0.0;
    Point3[] point = new Point3[2];
    point[0] = new Point3(i, j, k);
    point[1] = new Point3(2*i, 2*j, 2*k);

    System.out.println("Point3: "+point);


    MatOfPoint3f objectCorners;

    objectCorners = new MatOfPoint3f(point[0]);
    System.out.println("1-objectCorners"+objectCorners.toList());   

    objectCorners.fromArray(point);
    System.out.println("2-objectCorners:"+objectCorners);

    objectCorners.fromArray(point[1]);
    System.out.println("3-objectCorners"+objectCorners.toList());
```

And I get this results in console:

```
Point3: [Lorg.opencv.core.Point3;@5e222e
1-objectCorners[{2.0, 4.0, 0.0}]
2-objectCorners:Mat [ 2*1*CV_32FC3, isCont=true, isSubmat=false, nativeObj=0x539a320, dataAddr=0x539e310 ]
3-objectCorners[{4.0, 8.0, 0.0}]
```

Comment: Have you given the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/java/) a look? I expect `get()` and `put()` will be of use. Also, it's not totally clear what you are asking for. What does "maintain the old data" mean?

Comment: Hi, I have edited my question. I hope it gets more clear. The methods get() and put() are not declared for the class MatOfPoint3f

Comment: They should be declared. `MatOfPoint3f` inherits from `Mat`. As to your edit, that is the behavior I would expect. Perhaps you should include code in your question that demonstrates your problem or what you are trying to accomplish. I still don't fully understand what it is that you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer, but can still help someone.
I used the method put() with a double[] and it worked.
I modified the y from 4.0 to 5.0.

```
    java.util.List<Point3> pointsList = new ArrayList<Point3>();
    MatOfPoint3f pointsMat = new MatOfPoint3f();

    int i = 2;
    int j = 4;
    double k = 0.0;
    Point3[] point = new Point3[2];
    point[0] = new Point3(i, j, k);
    point[1] = new Point3(2*i, 2*j, 2*k);

    pointsList.add(point[0]);
    pointsList.add(point[1]);

    // MatOfPoint3f from List
    pointsMat.fromList(pointsList);

    // Index of element to change
    int elementIndex = 0;

    System.out.println("Before modifying");
    Point3 readedPoint = pointsMat.toList().get(elementIndex);
    System.out.println(readedPoint);

    // Modify a point

    point[elementIndex].y = 5.0; // Changing y to 5.0 for example

    double[] modified = {point[elementIndex].x, point[elementIndex].y, point[elementIndex].z};
    pointsMat.put(0, elementIndex, modified);

    System.out.println("After modifying");
    readedPoint = pointsMat.toList().get(elementIndex);
    System.out.println(readedPoint);
```

Console output:

```
Before modifying
{2.0, 4.0, 0.0}
After modifying
{2.0, 5.0, 0.0}
```